# applying transformation on multiple object which are inside a single container

Tags: actionscript-3

I am developing a paint board application using flash builder. User can draw some shapes objects(ellipse, circle, rectangle). I want to implement grouping/un grouping feature some like ms-word in my application. I group multiple objects by putting them inside a container(UIComponent). Now i apply resizing to container and it resize well. I am using a free object handler API to apply selection handle over the container. I want to resize and reposition all children with respect to container changed size. Every thing goes well until all children inside container are having rotation = 0. But if there is any child which is having rotation >0 and <0 things goes worse. The child resize but not in a proper manner. I stretch the parent container width and it increase the height of rotated child. Is there any way using Matrix class or something else to transform all children in same direction and same ratio respective to container?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Flash Professional? In my experience, placing objects within a symbol is the best route has been easiest to achieve this for me.

1. Select all the objects you want to link together (can also include existing symbols)
2. Right click and select 'Create Symbol'
3. Name the symbol what you'd like, then click okay

You can then freely transform any instance of that symbol, which retains the relationship between the objects within (including rotation).

Comment: Thanks Russell, i am using flash builder to develop a drawing application. Where i have some custom shape object like ellipse, rectangle, freehand, diamond etc. I draw all these in to separate uicomponent an put them on a canvas. Now i want to group selected shape objects and want to apply transform over this grouped object. Grouped object is simply a canvas. If shape objects are having rotation 0 then i don't face any problem while transforming the group object. But when rotation is >0 & <0 it become difficult to manage transform of shape object with respect to group object.